# mysql - how to get number of unique active users per month who posted or commented?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

**content**: content_id, user_id, post_date

**comment**: comment_id, user_id, comment_date

How can I get a count of active unique users grouped by month and year?
Active would mean that the user either posted or commented in that given month.

Comment: 1) If a user posts and comments in the same month, should it be counted twice? 2) If a user posts and comments in different months, should it be counted on each month?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  T.action_year,
  T.action_month,
  COUNT(T.user_id) active_users
FROM
  (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id, YEAR(post_date) action_year, MONTH(post_date) action_month FROM content
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id, YEAR(comment_date) action_year, MONTH(comment_date) action_date FROM comment
  ) T
GROUP BY
  T.action_year,
  T.action_month
ORDER BY
  T.action_year ASC,
  T.action_month ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not tested.

```
select count(table1.user_id), table1.user_id
from table1 table2 
where table1.user_id = table2.user_id
And table2.comment_date like 'may'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select TO_CHAR(order_dt,'MON-YYYY'), count(distinct User_ID ) cnt from [orders] 
where User_ID  in 
(select User_ID from
 (select a.User_ID from  [orders] a,
(select a.User_ID,count (a.order_dt) from [orders] a 
where a.order_dt > (select max(b.order_dt)-365 from [orders] b where a.User_ID=b.User_ID)
group by a.User_ID
having count(order_dt)>1) b
where a.User_ID=b.User_ID) a
)
group by TO_CHAR(order_dt,'MON-YYYY');
```